# reactjs scroll to bottom with user defined speed when user click start button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to add auto scrolling div for lyric when user is click play scroll button with speed. There is speed button to increase or decrease speed of scrolling.

So far I only achieved that it is scrolling to bottom.

I use useRef and trackRef.current.scrollIntoView. window.scrollto is not working.

May I know how to scroll div with speed until I can see the all hidden part of the bottom.

here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { getTrack, getTrackVariable } from "../../gql/track";
import ChordSheetJS from "chordsheetjs";
import { PlayIcon, PauseIcon } from "../../assets/icons/svg_icons";
import { SettingIcon } from "../../assets/icons/svg_icons";

const TrackPage = () => {
  const { trackId } = useParams();
  const [track, setTrack] = useState();
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(true);
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getTrack, {
    variables: getTrackVariable(trackId),
  });

  const trackRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !error) {
      setTrack(data?.track);
    }
  }, [loading, error, data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (play) {
      trackRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "end",
        inline: "start",
      });
    }
  }, [play]);

  const getChordSheet = (value) => {
    const parser = new ChordSheetJS.ChordProParser();
    const song = parser.parse(value);
    const formatter = new ChordSheetJS.HtmlTableFormatter();
    const chordSheet = formatter.format(song);
    return chordSheet;
  };

  const handleError = (e) => {
    e.target.onerror = null;
    e.target.src = Monk;
  };

  const handleMenuCollapse = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCollapse(!collapse);
  };

  const handleSpeedUp = () => {
    setSpeed(speed + 1);
  };

  const handleSpeedDown = () => {
    setSpeed(speed - 1);
  };

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPlay(!play);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="setting">
        {/** the big div */}
        <div
          className={` w-36 h-56  bg-primary absolute top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)]  ${
            collapse ? "hidden" : "right-0"
          } " bg-primary rounded-b-lg items-center justify-center`}
        >
          <div>
            <div className="items-center justify-center mt-5">
              <div className="flex text-xs items-center justify-center ">
                <span className=" text-sm text-white">Scroll</span>
              </div>
              <div className="flex text-xs pt-0 mt-0 items-center justify-center ">
                <button
                  className="px-2 btn-sm flex w-20 items-center bg-transparent hover:bg-accent border text-white font-semibold hover:text-white border-white hover:border-transparent rounded "
              onClick={handleScroll}
            >
              {play ? (
                <PauseIcon className="text-white mr-2" />
              ) : (
                <PlayIcon className="text-white mr-2" />
              )}
              {play ? <span>Pause</span> : <span>Play</span>}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex text-xs items-center justify-center mt-2">
            <button
              className="w-auto bg-transparent mr-2 hover:bg-accent text-white font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-2 border border-white hover:border-transparent rounded"
              onClick={handleSpeedDown}
            >
              -1
            </button>
            <button
              className="w-auto bg-transparent ml-2 hover:bg-accent text-white font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-2 border border-white hover:border-transparent rounded"
              onClick={handleSpeedUp}
            >
              +1
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {/** the icon div */}
    <div
      className={`flex w-12 absolute  top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)] h-12 bg-primary
            ${collapse ? "animate-pulse right-0" : "right-36"}
            cursor-pointer bg-primary rounded-l-lg items-center justify-center`}
      onClick={handleMenuCollapse}
    >
      {/* <div className="w-5 h-5 bg-white rounded-full " /> */}
      <SettingIcon />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ref={trackRef}>
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full py-1 my-1 items-center bg-gray-50">
      <div className="relative my-6 mx-auto md:min-w-[60%] max-h-full">
        {track ? (
          <div className="w-full">
            <pre
              className="px-5 textarea"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: getChordSheet(track.lyric),
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
  );
};

export default TrackPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

window.scrollTo is only working with html body. document.getElementById is only working overflow div.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (play) {
  const onScrollStep = () => {
    var e = document.getElementById("content");
    if (e.scrollHeight - e.scrollTop === e.clientHeight) {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      setPlay(!play);
      return;
    }
    e.scroll(0, e.scrollTop + speed);
  };
  intervalId.current = setInterval(onScrollStep, delayInMs);
} else {
  clearInterval(intervalId.current);
}
},[play, speed])
```